# Python Pandas Merge two CSV based on Time Stamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

Could someone give me a tip on how to merge two CSV files based on time stamp? Concat works, but I also need to organize the data based on ***one*** single stamp, DateTime. In the shell output snip below both DateTime columns are visible. Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

WUdata = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\bbartling\\Documents\\Python\\test_SP 
data\\3rd GoRound k Nearest\\WB data\\WU\\WUdata.csv')

print(WUdata.describe())
print(WUdata.shape)
print(WUdata.columns)
print(WUdata.info())

kWdata = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\bbartling\\Documents\\Python\\test_SP 
data\\3rd GoRound k Nearest\\WB data\\WU\\kWdata.csv')

print(kWdata.describe())
print(kWdata.shape)
print(kWdata.columns)
print(kWdata.info())

merged = pd.concat([WUdata, kWdata], axis=1)

print(merged)
```

[image]

Comment: See this question on how to ask a good Pandas question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "based on time stamp", and "organize the data". Do you want to concatenate two dataframes and align on the DataTime columns?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to merge the data sets together organized by date & time. Each data set has the same exact time stampt. And if there is a data is both datasets on exactly the same date & time, I think one of the time stamps would need to be eliminated...? Thanks